# Where can I find the latest version of the CAB File Wizard (Cabwiz.exe)?

Tags: windows-mobile, cab

I need to use CabWiz for a legacy mobile project but I can't install the Windows Mobile SDK.

Where can I find the latest version of the CAB File Wizard (Cabwiz.exe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download [Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK Refresh.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6135).
2. Extract the contents of the `.msi` file using [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/):

   ```
   7z.exe x "Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK Refresh.msi"
   ```
3. Extract the contents of `sdkfiles.cab`:

   ```
   7z.exe x sdkfiles.cab
   ```
4. Find the following files and rename them:

   - `CGen_Common_CabWiz_Cabwiz.exe => Cabwiz.exe`
   - `CGen_Common_CabWiz_makecab.exe => makecab.exe`
   - `CGen_Common_CabWiz_cabwiz.ddf => cabwiz.ddf`

If you check the *Details* property of `Cabwiz.exe` you should find it has version 4.5.5102.